# Player movement starts after a few seconds after pressing the button

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm following a tutorial on **Unity 5** to create a simple stealth game.

I followed the instructions to create the script that controls the **movement of the player**. When I tested the game I noticed that the player **takes a few seconds** after pressing the button **before moving**.

It's as if before moving should await the conclusion of the rotation that is performed by `Quaternion.Lerp`.

Also pressing the **x button** should scream to attract attention and take proper animation.. It runs the sound but **the animation is not done**.. Was performed only once in multiple tests I did.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public AudioClip shoutingClip;      // Audio clip of the player shouting.
    public float turnSmoothing = 15f;   // A smoothing value for turning the player.
    public float speedDampTime = 0.1f;  // The damping for the speed parameter


    private Animator anim;              // Reference to the animator component.
    private HashIDs hash;               // Reference to the HashIDs.


    void Awake ()
    {
        // Setting up the references.
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        hash = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(Tags.gameController).GetComponent<HashIDs>();

        // Set the weight of the shouting layer to 1.
        anim.SetLayerWeight(1, 1f);
    }


    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Cache the inputs.
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        bool sneak = Input.GetButton("Sneak");

        MovementManagement(h, v, sneak);
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        // Cache the attention attracting input.
        bool shout = Input.GetButtonDown("Attract");

        // Set the animator shouting parameter.
        anim.SetBool(hash.shoutingBool, shout);

        AudioManagement(shout);
    }


    void MovementManagement (float horizontal, float vertical, bool sneaking)
    {
        // Set the sneaking parameter to the sneak input.
        anim.SetBool(hash.sneakingBool, sneaking);

        // If there is some axis input...
        if(horizontal != 0f || vertical != 0f)
        {
            // ... set the players rotation and set the speed parameter to 5.5f.
            Rotating(horizontal, vertical);
            anim.SetFloat(hash.speedFloat, 5.5f, speedDampTime, Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
            // Otherwise set the speed parameter to 0.
            anim.SetFloat(hash.speedFloat, 0);
    }


    void Rotating (float horizontal, float vertical)
    {
        // Create a new vector of the horizontal and vertical inputs.
        Vector3 targetDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical);

        // Create a rotation based on this new vector assuming that up is the global y axis.
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection, Vector3.up);

        // Create a rotation that is an increment closer to the target rotation from the player's rotation.
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation, targetRotation, turnSmoothing * Time.deltaTime);

        // Change the players rotation to this new rotation.
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MoveRotation(newRotation);
    }


    void AudioManagement (bool shout)
    {
        // If the player is currently in the run state...
        if(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).nameHash == hash.locomotionState)
        {
            // ... and if the footsteps are not playing...
            if(!GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying)
                // ... play them.
                GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
        else
            // Otherwise stop the footsteps.
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();

        // If the shout input has been pressed...
        if(shout)
            // ... play the shouting clip where we are.
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(shoutingClip, transform.position);
    }
}
```

I'm new in unity so I might need some more explanation. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue, delaying your player movement, may be caused by the line

```
anim.SetFloat(hash.speedFloat, 5.5f, speedDampTime, Time.deltaTime);
```

The potential issue is that you are calling **Time.deltaTime**, which is intended to be use inside an **update()** call. Your function is called inside of **fixedUpdate()** which means you should be using **Time.fixedDeltaTime**.

For your second issue, shouting, the code seems fine and the issue is likely in your animation tree. Check that the state you are in before shouting can transition to shout, and checks for the correct trigger.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a problem in the transition for shouting, I solved the problem. 
About the player movement, the problem was in the transitions that had the check on "Has Exit Time". Anyway thanks for the tip on the code, I think it is more correct.